# Automated way to find all GET requests made when accessing a website

Tags: java, python, http, selenium, networking

I'm trying to find an automated way of collecting a list of all GET requests that are made when accessing a given website, in particular those that get resources that reside in other domains. Ultimately I would like to have this run automatically for thousands of websites.

The most promising approach I have found so far is selenium, and in particular [this somewhat old project](https://code.google.com/archive/p/selenium-profiler/) which I was able to run by installing older versions of selenium (in particular, the standalone server version 2.53.2, and the python selenium client version 1.0.3). This has a *captureNetworkTraffic* option with which the server returns a list of all requests, among other things.

When running the script, it returns a list of results, among which the GET requests (looks as follows):

```
http timing detail: (status, method, doc, size, time)
204, GET, /generate_204, 0, 62 ms
200, GET, /favicon.ico, 1150, 31 ms
200, GET, /barcode09.gif, 3011, 31 ms
200, GET, /, 3451, 110 ms
200, GET, /2cca7b2e99206b9c.js, 3451, 78 ms
200, GET, /nav_logo7.png, 5401, 16 ms
200, GET, /f_wkquEsVv8.js, 14632, 47 ms
```

However, when looking into the code, I found that the full paths returned look something like http://localhost:4444/favicon.ico,
so the information about the original domain, which is what I'm interested in, is lost.

Any ideas on how to get the server to return the original URL? Also a different approach that will get me the information I need would be most appreciated (if possible in python or java).

Comment: How deep do you need to go? Say you retrieve a HTML document that references external CSS or JS, and those resources in turn had further external references, would you want them? If not, and you don't need the timing info, it'd probably be simplest to use requests + lxml (python libs) to parse the HTML document.

Comment: I would suggest to use a proxy. That does automatically have have full list of all requests. Maybe `Charly` can be of help here. Or take a look at a `socks5` impementation, that would actually give you the source code which you can modify for your own means.

Comment: Interesting approach @arkascha! I didn't immediately think of that. Especially if the order of requests and network timings is important. If not I still think a single "scraper" style solution would be simplest (e.g. Scrapy).

Comment: @dwightgunning A scraper will not produce a realistic protocol, since it tries to interpret the content itself, usually different than a "real" browser. I'd say observing a browser as it is used under normal circumstances will give the most realistic result.

Comment: @arkascha you're correct with the assumption the OP needs to record browser-like behaviour. If they're just looking for referenced hosts/resources then it's not such a big deal.

Comment: thanks a lot for your replies! Yes, a proxy seems to be the best option for what I need. Since selenium is already running a proxy, I was hoping that there would be an option to just get it to return the full URLs, but that is unlikely I guess. I found [this simple proxy](http://www.jtmelton.com/2007/11/27/a-simple-multi-threaded-java-http-proxy-server/) which seems promising.

Comment: Try out [Browsermob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)